# Pushwoosh Phonegap notifications PHP method set tags

Tags: php, javascript, android, cordova, push-notification

I am not a professional programmer. I manage with PHP and Javascript, but I am having a hard time converting Pushwoosh methods to functional PHP or Javascript. This is the method that I need help converting:

Method /setTags

Set tags values for device

Request:

```
{
  "request":{
    "application":"DEAD0-BEEF0",
    "hwid": 'device hardware id',
    "tags": {
      "tag1": "string value",
      "tag2": 42,
      "tag3": "string",
      "tag4": 3.14
    }
  }
}
```

This is how they post their methods. Any help with this?

I wrote a PHP to setTags but I could not verify it yet as I am still working on retrieving the Token. I have a question on that on  this link:

[Phonegap/Pushwoosh Android retrieving Device id / Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633236/phonegap-pushwoosh-android-retrieving-device-id-token)

this is my PHP for setTags. Does this look right using JSON? (I am running late on my project!)

```
<?php

define('PW_AUTH', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('PW_APPLICATION', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
define('HW_ID', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

function doPostRequest($url, $data, $optional_headers = null) {
    $params = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $data
        ));
    if ($optional_headers !== null)
        $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;

    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
    $fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
    if (!$fp)
        throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errmsg");

    $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
    if ($response === false)
        return false;
    return $response;
}

function pwCall( $action, $data = array() ) {
    $url = 'https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/' . $action;
    $json = json_encode( array( 'request' => $data ) );
    $res = doPostRequest( $url, $json, 'Content-Type: application/json' );
    print_r( @json_decode( $res, true ) );
}

pwCall( 'setTags', array(
    'application' => PW_APPLICATION,
    'auth' => PW_AUTH,
    'hwid' => HW_ID,
    'tags' => array(
                array(
                    'tag1' => 'string value',
                    'tag2' => 42,
                    'tag3' => 'string',
                    'tag4' => 3.14
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

?>

Comment: the link to pushwoosh RemoteAPI guide http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need to convert this JSON to send tags to Pushwoosh. It's being sent directly from the device to the Pushwoosh server.